# Detect if a system hotkey already defined with DDHotKey/Carbon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, ddhotkey

I'm trying to figure out how I can allow a user to customize their hotkey selection without stomping on an already configured system hotkey. Anybody implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my memory is correct the [shortcut recorder framework](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/) implements this and it's BSD-licensed, so take a look at the source code there?

Comment: Right on. Took SR and pealed off the validator code. So far so good.

Comment: Could you maybe post an entry point to the code for later reference? I guess it could be useful for other programmers as well.